# Sharepoint 2010 webpart vb.net Listbox SelectIndexChanged and Button click

Tags: vb.net

webpart vb.bet 2010 not visual webpart
I want to grab the selectindexchanged, and run the code after button click.
I only really need is the SelectedItem.Text

here's how I did it in VB.net asp page.

```
Protected Sub listbox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Click_button
```

But SharePoint doesn't see this as valid handle.

any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Handles Click_button
```

try

```
Handles buttonName.Click
```

following `Handles <controlName>.<EventName>`

Comment: get the same error: Error 101 Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.